# Extendscript Photoshop: Is there a way to save out jpeg with specific KB file sizes for web?

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

I'm trying to utilize the following. what this does is saves out Jpeg accordingly to less then a a certain size set. I was curious if anyone knew a way to specifically direct a filename to get a filesize that is equal to the following or as close as possible.

Filename_160x600.png = Filename_160x600.jpg   39kb

Filename_300x600.png = Filename_300x600.jpg   59kb

Filename_1500x513.png = Filename_1500x513.jpg 150kb

```
         saveJPG(
         {
         path: activeDocument.path,
         maxSize: 50 //size in kbs
         })

        function saveJPG(_data)
    {
    if (_data.path == undefined) return false;
    _data.name = _data.name == undefined ? activeDocument.name : _data.name;
    _data.quality == undefined && _data.quality = 75;

    if (!new Folder(_data.path).exists)


{
        alert("Output path doesn't exist!"); //you can add a function to create a path if needed
        return false
    }

    var options = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb(),
        jpgFile = new File(_data.path + '/' + getName(_data.name) + '.jpg');

    options.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
    options.quality = _data.quality;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(jpgFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, options);
    if (_data.maxSize != undefined)
    {
        var ms = _data.maxSize * 1000;
        if (jpgFile.length > ms)
        {
            if (!jpgFile.remove())
            {
                alert('Save file is locked, please make sure it\'s not opened anywhere');
                return
            };
            saveJPG(
            {
                path: _data.path,
                name: _data.name,
                maxSize: _data.maxSize,
                quality: _data.quality - 2
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the code snippet works, but you want three different sizes (39kb, 59kb and 150kb) instead of just 50kb? Then just call the function from within an if statement checking if the filename contains the desired string. Something like `if (myFilename.search("160x600")>0){saveJPEG({maxSize: 39})}`

Comment: I tried adding the following to the script and it comes back erroring on this line..       if (activeDocument.search("160x600")>0){saveJPEG({maxSize: 39})}  does it need an else if or a return of some sort?

Comment: i also tried the following but it kept coming back as an error for the return value..

  if (activeDocument.search("160x600")>0)
        {
            if (activeDocument.search("300x600")>0)
            {
                alert('160x600!');
               return
            };
            saveJPG(
            {
                path: activeDocument.path,
               maxSize: 50 //size in kbs
            });

Comment: You don't want to search the `ActiveDocument`, you want to search `activeDocument.name` like this: `activeDocument.name.search("160x600")`