# Extendscript: Photoshop scripting IF activedocument Proper syntax

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

Im having issues trying to do the following. It keeps stopping at the return attribute. Thanks! I want this to check for various filenames and then change the output for those values.. thx.

```
  if (activeDocument.search("160x600")>0)
    {
        if (activeDocument.search("300x600")>0)
        {
           path: activeDocument.path,
           maxSize: 59 //size in kbs
           return
        };
        saveJPG(
        {
            path: activeDocument.path,
           maxSize: 39 //size in kbs
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

(taking the numbers from your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341077/extendscript-photoshop-is-there-a-way-to-save-out-jpeg-with-specific-kb-file-si?noredirect=1#comment91698741_52341077), you probably want somethinglike this:

```
if (activeDocument.name.search("160x600")>0)
    {
    maxSize: 39
    }

else if (activeDocument.name.search("300x600")>0)
    {
    maxSize: 59
    }

else if (activeDocument.name.search("1500x513")>0)
    {
    maxSize: 150
    }

else
    {
    alert ('document not saved')

    }
```

Afterward, you can call the saveJPG function, passing whatever value of maxSize has been selected

Comment: for some reason it just stops at that first if command dead in its tracks. i have no idea why.. :(

Comment: There was a copy paste error on my part there. Sorry about that. See edited version